# Removing word from the beginning of my text object?

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk

I have a function that scrapes speeches from millercenter.org and returns the processed speech. However, every one of my speeches has the word "transcript" at the beginning (that's just how it's coded into the HTML). So, all of my text files look like this:

```
\n <--- there's really just a new line, here, not literally '\n'
transcript

fourscore and seven years ago, blah blah blah
```

I have these saved in my U:/ drive - how can I iterate through these files and remove 'transcript'? The files look like this, essentially:

[image: link]

Edit:

```
speech_dict = {}
for filename in glob.glob("U:/FALL 2015/ENGL 305/NLP Project/Speeches/*.txt"):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inputFile:
        filecontent = inputFile.read();
        filecontent.replace('transcript','',1)
        speech_dict[filename] = filecontent # put the speeches into a dictionary to run through the algorithm
```

This is not doing anything to change my speeches. 'transcript' is still there.

I also tried putting it into my text-processing function, but that doesn't work, either:

```
def processURL(l):
        open_url = urllib2.urlopen(l).read()
        item_soup = BeautifulSoup(open_url)
        item_div = item_soup.find('div',{'id':'transcript'},{'class':'displaytext'})
        item_str = item_div.text.lower()
        item_str_processed = punctuation.sub(' ',item_str)
        item_str_processed_final = item_str_processed.replace('—',' ').replace('transcript','',1)

        splitlink = l.split("/")
        president = splitlink[4]
        speech_num = splitlink[-1]
        filename = "{0}_{1}".format(president, speech_num)

        return filename, item_str_processed_final # giving back filename and the text itself
```

Here's an example url I run through `processURL`: http://millercenter.org/president/harding/speeches/speech-3805

Comment: read each file onto a string with `f.read()` then either `replace` like @Will said or slice the data with `data.strip()[len('transcript'):]` then write back to the same file using `'w'` parameter to overwrite the existing file

Comment: GBR24, it isn't at all clear which part of this is causing you trouble. Are you asking how to create a Python program, how to execute a Python program, how to do file i/o, how to code a `for` loop, or how to delete a substring from a string? Don't answer that rhetorical question: rather, get started writing the script yourself. When you reach a dead end, show us what you've done and ask a more specific question.

Comment: @RNar Good call on slicing, I think could also be `data = data.split()[1:]` This remove the first word though (regardless of what it is), so any malformed files will become more malformed.

Comment: this is definitely cleaner than straight string slicing

Comment: seeing your edit, `.replace` method returns a COPY of your string. because strings are immutable, you can't do inplace replacements into it. reassign filecontents like `filecontents = filecontents.replace(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Python's excellent `replace()` for this:

```
data = data.replace('transcript', '', 1)
```

This line will replace `'transcript'` with `''` (empty string). The final parameter is the number of replacements to make.  1 for only the first instance of `'transcript'`, blank for all instances.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the data you want always starts on line x then do this:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for _ in range(x): # This loop will skip x no. of lines.
        next(fin)
    for line in fin:
        # do something with the line.
        print(line)
```

Or let's say you want to remove any lines before transcript:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as fin:
    while next(fin) != 'transcript': # This loop will skip lines until it reads the *transcript* lines.
        break
    # if you want to skip the empty line after *transcript*
    next(fin) # skips the next line.
    for line in fin:
        # do something with the line.
        print(line)
```